# How do i get my "onGoing" Notification to appear at the bottom of the drawer?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a long-running status that i illustrate with an ongoing notification. This works fine insofar as it can't be swiped away etc.

However, other ongoing notifications such as the "Cable charging" and "Transferring media" appear in the bottom, below all the "normal" ones.

I would like mine to appear there too, so that it does not distract from the regular application notifications, but i can't seem to find a way to do so. I have tried playing around with the Priority, but that does nothing.

Is there any way to specify the Notification in such a way?

Comment: Does SnackBar solves this for you?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I don't want it for a short period of time, but for hours and sometimes days. Just like the "Cable charging" and other similar notifications.

Comment: So you mean intermitents Notifications

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAG_NO_CLEAR

```
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

And you will need to take care to cancel it by its ID sometime later.